# API failure SSL installation error on cpanel

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel

When i  try to install ssl on whm for domain get following error
API failure: Missing “cert”! at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SSL/Objects/Certificate.pm line 36.